# How to listen for UDP datagrams from a certain host using recvfrom?

Tags: c, udp

I have a C code snippet that listens on UDP socket for incomming messages (and it works fine):

```
uint32_t udp_port = 101010; // example port
int sock_udp = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
server_address.sin_port = htons(udp_port);
bind(sock_udp, (struct sockaddr*) &server_address, (socklen_t) sizeof(server_address));

char buffer[20];
struct sockaddr_in sender_address;
socklen_t sender_len = (socklen_t) sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
ssize_t rcv_len = recvfrom(sock_udp, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr * ) &sender_address, &sender_len);
```

After it I have information on the sender in sender_address structure and I can check addres, port etc. My question is: can I use `recv`, `recvfrom` or other similar function to listen for datagrams coming from a certain host? In other words, is it possible to drop datagrams from other sources without reading them?

Comment: You forget to fill in `sender_len` before calling `recvfrom`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "filter" and receive datagrams from a specified single source if you [`connect(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) the datagram socket.

> If the socket sockfd is of type `SOCK_DGRAM` then addr is the address to
>   which datagrams are sent by default, **and the only address from which
>   datagrams are received**.

[The standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) phrases it a little different:

> For `SOCK_DGRAM` sockets, the peer address identifies where all
>   datagrams are sent on subsequent `send()` functions, and limits the
>   remote sender for subsequent `recv()` functions

Comment: Shall I `connect` instead of `bind`-ing, or after it?

Comment: @WojciechPtak Do it after `bind`ing.